# iCloud Website - NoSuchElementException: Unable to Locate Element

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to make a program that involves me logging into Gmail and iCloud, using Selenium. I've completed the Gmail part, so I know I'm not completely off track, but I can't seem to surmount the error that occurs when I try to locate the login/password fields on the iCloud website. I keep getting:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate
>   element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="appleId"]"}

I've attempted to use `WebDriverWait`, and I've done waits for like 30 seconds just to see if timing was the issue, but I keep getting the same error even if I try to locate the login/password fields using Xpath, ID name, CSS selector, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's within an iframe so you need to have Selenium switch to it.

`driver.switch_to.frame('auth-frame')`

Once you do that you should be able to locate it by id or xpath.

Comment: Thank you, but now I'm getting a no such frame exception?

Comment: It works for me on icloud.com, if you're on a different page the iframe's id may be different. Or Selenium may be looking for the iframe before it exists.

Comment: You're right, I just forgot to wait. I made it wait now until the frame was available, but then I had to wait again for the login field to be available, so I set it to an arbitrary wait time. I've tried to make it wait until it was present, but for some reason that doesn't work (i.e. login = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, 'loginXPath')))...I keep getting the error that __init___() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given. But this is the way I've seen it all over the Internet so what elements should I put inside?

Comment: Never mind, an extra pair of parentheses fixed the problem. Thank you!